# how to get number of spoken words in SpeechSynthesizer

Tags: c#-4.0, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis, part-of-speech

I am new in C# and I'm using SpeechSynthesizer to read out some words. But I need to count how many words I've spoken while I'm speaking. Is there any method for that?? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `System.Speech.Synthesizer.SpeakProgress` event for this. See the following code,

```
    int WordCount = 0;
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();
                synthesizer.SpeakProgress += new EventHandler<System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeakProgressEventArgs>(synthesizer_SpeakProgress);
                synthesizer.SpeakAsync("Hello How Are You?");
            }

    void synthesizer_SpeakProgress(object sender, System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeakProgressEventArgs e)
            {
                WordCount++;
                //To Write word count
                Console.WriteLine(WordCount.toString());
                //To Write each word and its character postion to the console.
                Console.WriteLine("CharPos: {0}   CharCount: {1}   AudioPos: {2}    \"{3}\"", e.CharacterPosition, e.CharacterCount, e.AudioPosition, e.Text);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there's the [`System.Speech.Synthesizer.SpeakProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.speakprogress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.  That event has a character count and character position (from the start of the string) that you can use to count words.  (You might even get an event per word, although I'm not sure that's true for all languages.)